# Обязательные атрибуты в интерфейсах Python

Tags: python, ооп

Как при создании "интерфейсов" в Python назначить обязательные атрибуты/свойства для классов, которые этот интерфейс реализуют?

Допустим, обязательные методы реализуются через `@abc.abstractmethod`. Класс без них падает с ошибкой при инициализации.

*Вижу что раньше был декоратор `@abc.abstractproperty`, но сейчас он помечен как `deprecated`...

Comment: Не знаю как в Python, но в стандартном ООП понятие "интерфейс" подразумевает, что ВСЕ методы абстрактные и, следовательно, обязательные к реализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property
@abstractmethod
def my_property(self):
   pass
```

Можно попробовать задать сразу два декоратора.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример как my_property должен объявляться в наследующем классе

Comment: Если вообще моя проблема имеет смысл ("требование у наследников реализовать атрибут..."). С ООП плохо знаком, может обычно есть только потребность в методах (у наследников)?